# How to convert this XML into a table using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Please suggest how to write the XSLT for the below XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="list8.xsl"?>
<SeminarDetails>
  <CourseName>XML Introduction</CourseName>
  <Code>1234</Code>
  <Content1>
    <Chapter1>XML Overview</Chapter1>
    <Chapter1>XML Document Creation</Chapter1>
    <Chapter1>DTD</Chapter1>
    <Chapter1>XML Schema</Chapter1>
    <Chapter1>XSLT, XPath</Chapter1>
    <Chapter1>Namespace</Chapter1>
  </Content1>
  <Content2>
    <Chapter2>XML basics</Chapter2>
    <Chapter2>XML Document basics Creation1</Chapter2>
    <Chapter2>Description</Chapter2>
    <Chapter2>XML Schema1</Chapter2>
  </Content2>
</SeminarDetails>
```

I need 3 columns like below:

```
Code  Content1                Content2
1234  XML Overview            XML basics
      XML Document Creation   XML Document basics Creation1
      DTD                     Description
      XML Schema
      XSLT, XPath
```

Comment: Do you want text or HTML output?

Comment: I need TEXT output...

Comment: Please state XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Hi Michael, I dont have much idea about XSLT versions. I guess it should be 1.0. please guide me.

Comment: Also your text format is not entirely clear: are those tab characters separating the cells in the same row, or do you need a variable amount of space characters?

Comment: my actual output should be of a table with 3 columns CODE, CONTENT1 and CONTENT2 and corresponding data populated in it.

Comment: just those tab characters are separating the cells in the same row @hughes

Comment: just to want clarify... I dont want everything in the same line...I need output like a table format..

Answer (score 0):

**Given your input XML document, the following XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="SeminarDetails">
    <xsl:text>Code&#x9;Content1&#x9;Content2&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Code"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="Content1/*">
      <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:variable name="posContent1" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="../../Content2/*[position() = $posContent1]"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- In case Content2 has more children than Content1... -->
    <xsl:variable name="countContent1" select="count(Content1/*)"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="Content2/*[position() > $countContent1]">
      <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Will produce the desired (tab-separated) output:**

```
Code    Content1    Content2
1234    XML Overview    XML basics
    XML Document Creation   XML Document basics Creation1
    DTD Description
    XML Schema  XML Schema1
    XSLT, XPath 
    Namespace
```

**Which looks as follows when pasted into a spreadsheet:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be more elegant - esp. if you can use **XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/SeminarDetails">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>Code&#9;Content1&#9;Content2&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- define column contents -->
    <xsl:variable name="col-0" select="Code" />
    <xsl:variable name="col-a" select="Content1/Chapter1" />
    <xsl:variable name="col-b" select="Content2/Chapter2" />
    <!-- generate rows -->
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to max(((count($col-a)), (count($col-b))))">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="." />
        <xsl:value-of select="$col-0[$i]"/>
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>   
        <xsl:value-of select="$col-a[$i]"/>
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>   
        <xsl:value-of select="$col-b[$i]"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the output is to be copied to MS-Excel the tab separated output is usefull. When however the output is to be published on a website it is also to usefull to know how to blend the output in html. Furthermore I allways recommend to benefit from the recursive power of XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SeminarDetails">
  <STYLE> TD {vertical-align:top} </STYLE>
     <H1><xsl:apply-templates select="CourseName" /></H1>
     <TABLE border="1">
     <TR>
     <TD><xsl:apply-templates select="Code" /></TD>
     <TD><xsl:apply-templates select="Content1" /></TD>
     <TD><xsl:apply-templates select="Content2" /></TD>
     </TR></TABLE>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CourseName|Code|Chapter1|Chapter2">
     <xsl:copy-of select="." /><BR />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Content1|Content2">
     <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's also useful to know and benefit from the power of XSLT's  [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule). This would allow you to delete your first and last templates as redundant. And your third template should probably `match="Chapter1|Chapter2"` only, as I don't see what benefit appending a line break to the CourseName or Code brings. -- Other than that, you are kidding, right?  OP stated expressly in the comments (after being asked) that the output should be text, not HTML. But, as things go around here, your answer will very likely end up being the accepted one.