# xsl:for-each inside xsl:for-each in table rows and columns

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I've just started learning XML/XSL and I've hit a roadblock in one of my assignments. Tried Googling and searching over here but I can't seem to find a question that has a solution that is basic. so what I am trying is to display rows of bucket-type and room-types associated with it. can somebody please help

```
<list-inventory list-count="2">

<list  list-type="Standard" list-order = "1" count-Types = "3">
<types type="BEN2D"></room>
<types type="BESH2D"></room>
<types type="HNK"></room>
 </list>
 <list  list-type="Deluxe" list-order = "2" count-Types = "3">
<types type="SNK"></room>
<types type="TESTKD"></room>
<types type="TESTKD"></room>
</list>
<list-inventory>
```

I want table as below

```
Standard | Deluxe
BEN2D    |SNK
BESH2D   |TESTKD
HNK      |TESTKD
```

I tried below xsl code but i see all list-type in single column and only 1st  is being printing for all list-type:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="/contents/list-inventory/list">
    <tr>
    <td class="alt-th" style="border:1px solid black">
    <xsl:value-of select="@list-type"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">
    <xsl:for-each select="/contents/list-inventory/list/types">
    <span><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></span>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
      <br/>
     </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Can someone help me with xsl:for-each inside a xsl:for-each

Comment: This is much more difficult than what you seem to think. It's not possible to create a HTML table one column at a time. You must create it row-by-row and populate **all** cells of the row before moving to the next row. Not an exercise I would recommend to a beginner.

Comment: P.S. Your input is wrong: `</room>` does not close `<types>`.

Comment: See something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397648/how-to-convert-this-xml-into-a-table-using-xslt

Comment: "Tried Googling and searching over here but I can't seem to find a question that has a solution that is basic". That's no way to learn a programming language: you're never going to find code that does exactly what you want. You need to learn the language constructs and work out how to put them together yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It's too bad you did not post your expected result **as code**. I would assume that you want a separate row for each pair of values. As I stated in the comments, this is far from being trivial.

However, you could make it simpler if you are willing to settle for a single data row, where each cell contains  *all* the values of the corresponding `list` (your attempt seems to suggest that this is what you actually tried to accomplish).

So, given a **well-formed** XML input:

**XML**

```
<list-inventory list-count="2">
    <list list-type="Standard" list-order = "1" count-Types = "3">
        <types type="BEN2D"/>
        <types type="BESH2D"/>
        <types type="HNK"/>
    </list>
    <list list-type="Deluxe" list-order = "2" count-Types = "3">
        <types type="SNK"/>
        <types type="TESTKD"/>
        <types type="TESTKD"/>
    </list>
</list-inventory>
```

you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/list-inventory">
    <table border="1">
        <!-- header -->
        <tr> 
            <xsl:for-each select="list">
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@list-type"/>
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <!-- body -->
        <tr> 
            <xsl:for-each select="list">
                <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="types">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
                        <br/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>Standard</th>
      <th>Deluxe</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>BEN2D<br/>BESH2D<br/>HNK<br/>
      </td>
      <td>SNK<br/>TESTKD<br/>TESTKD<br/>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

which would render as:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how general you want your solution to be (i.e what inputs does it have to handle other than the example shown), but I would do something like:

```
  <xsl:template match="list-inventory">
    <xsl:variable name="list2" select="list[2]/types"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="list[1]/types">
      <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$list2[$position]/@type"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Both the variables here are needed to avoid problems with context: the effect of an XPath expression depends on the context at the time it is evaluated, so you can evaluate a variable to capture information at the time you're in the right context.

Comment: You are assuming that (a) there are at most two lists  and that (b) the size of the 2nd list is less or equal to the 1st.

Comment: Yes. I did state my assumptions.